# SQL if Record equals the record before it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to replicate a formula in excel into SQL, i have a list of customer ID codes with addresses.

I have concatenated the postcode and Surname and sorted them in ascending order.

I want to check if the the text string before equals the current one.

If it does then i want to put the ID number of the one before in a new field called New ID(on the current Record), and the old code in a new field called Deleted codes.

Basically we have duplicated addresses that we want to merge into one customer but without removing any data.

New code formula =IF(M20=M19,O19,A20)
Deleted Code Formula =IF(N20=O20,"",N20)

Is this possible to do in SQL?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sorry im using SQL SSMS 2008

Comment: It would help if we could see the structure of your table. I would suggest using dense_rank () instead of row_number() ie: select dense_rank() over (order by Textstring) as id,* from Table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY TextString) AS rn
    FROM   Table1
)
SELECT T1.TextString AS T1String,
       T2.TextString AS T2String,
       CASE WHEN T1.TextString = T2.TextString THEN T1.ID ELSE '' END AS NewCode,
       CASE WHEN T1.TextString = T2.TextString THEN T2.ID ELSE '' END AS OldCode
FROM   MyCTE T1
       LEFT JOIN MyCTE T2
           ON T1.rn = T2.rn+1
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efa8c/4)**

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how it works, just so i understand.

Comment: I give each row an incrementing number and i create a cte to hold them. Then i join the cte with itself using the id and the previous id. Then i am able to check the current string with the previous one.

Comment: In SQL 2012 and later you could use the new LAG function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code is running ok but i get a message saying Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.